# WIndows 10 opens directories and drives with VS Code when using double click instead of using the File Explorer

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, microsoft-file-explorer

I have only found solutions for Linux systems so here is the question for Windows:

If I open the Windows File Explorer and doubleclick any directory instead of opening it in the Explorer it opens it in vs code (same for drives). Deinstalling vs code helps, but reinstalling it adds the problem.

I had this problem for my Windows VM on work and I do not know why only there.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Open the registry (e.g. by using *Windows Key + R*, type `regedit` and press enter).
2. Go to the paths

   - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell
   - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\shell
   - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\background\shell
3. Delete the three folder named VScode

It is definitly no the most elegant solution, but better than None.

Sadly this also removed the tooltip `Open with VS Code`, but for me, it is worth it. If you reinstall it without the tooltip options it might also fix the issue, but I haven`t tried.